# OkHttp exclude APIs from caching

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, http-caching

I'm using Retrofit and OkHttp client for making network calls. My server supports Etag caching and I have added cache to
`okHttp` client . There are some APIs which I don't want to cache

This is my `okHttpClient` config

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient(Context context,
                                         HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor,Cache okHttpCache) {
            final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                    .cache(okHttpCache)
            return builder.build();
        }


    Cache cache(Context context) {
    return new Cache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "cache"),10 * 1024 * 1024);
     }
```

Can I ignore some of the APIs from caching?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using only OkHttp library then you could specify cache control policy as `CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK` to your request object. More info here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1496

If you are using OkHttp in couple with Retrofit, you could add `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to your request definition method inside your interface:
(spelling updated in example)

```
@Headers("Cache-Control: no-cache")
@GET("users/me")
Call<User> getUser();
```

Comment: Ok.I'm using OkHttp in couple with Retrofit, currently I have just added the cache to okHttp config as shown in my code. Will it enable cache for all the Apis? And whichever I dont want , I can override with `@Headers("Cahce-Contol: no-cache")` ?

Comment: If your back-end app handling cache policy passed over the request headers, then yes. If your server doesn't support it, then there is workaround based on request interceptor implementation.

Comment: if your server supports Etag caching mechanism, we are good to go with this config right?

Answer (score 0):

Okhttp3 Provides an Iterator for urls request in cache

```
public Iterator<String> urls() throws IOException {
  hasNext();
  next();
  remove();
}
```

You can simple use this to check against the APIs of interest and ignore it.
see doc http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html?is-external=true